# How can I pass overrides when using @use in the latest versions of SCSS?

Tags: sass

I'm in the process of building a sort of framework tool in 1.24.x SCSS and I'm having trouble figuring out how people will override the default values for variables. Here's a loose example:

```
// framework/_variable.scss

$variable-1: red !default;
```

```
// framework/_module.scss

@use "variable" as *;

@mixin mixin-one {
  color: $variable-1;
}
```

```
// framework/index.scss

@forward "module";
```

```
// project.scss

@use "framework" as * with (
  $variable-1: blue,
);
```

This gives me an error because `$variable-1` has already been imported by `framework/_module.scss` and cannot be overridden by a new import. Is it possible to circumvent this so that users of the framework can override the variables of the framework with their projects own properties?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question now, but for anyone else still finding it, the solution is to forward the variables / config file in your manifest before the modules importing them:

```
// framework/index.scss

@forward "variable";
@forward "module";
```

That will allow the user to change defaults before they're imported by the rest of your module. Those values will carry over into subsequent imports.